# Preventing WPF TreeView's SelectedItemChanged event from bubbling

Tags: wpf, treeview, event-bubbling, selecteditemchanged

I have a WPF `TreeView` which triggers a `SelectedItemChanged` event. Whenever I select an item in the `TreeView`, the `SelectedItemChanged` event is triggered for the selected item *and all of the selected node's ancestors in the tree*.

How do I prevent the `SelectedItemChanged` event from firing more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Set the `e.Handled` to `true` in the handler.</strike>

EDIT

As an update to this subject, view this blog [post](http://blog.tsells.com/2011/05/17/wpf-treeview-selecteditemchanged-event-firing-multiple-times/).

Comment: I'm using the Composite Application Library and the problem seems to stem from using EventAggregator to publish an event in the SelectedItemChaged event handler.

Comment: Turns out the problem is from some of my other code that was triggering the event... the above answer is still valid for the question in general.

Comment: It still bubbles for me as well, and also, your blog link is dead.

Comment: It seems this is a framework issue. I have updated the changed link.