# Preventing WPF TreeView's GotFocus event from bubbling up the tree

Tags: wpf, treeview, events, focus

I'm trying to write an event handler that fires every time a node in a TreeView gets the focus.  The problem I'm running into is that the event handler fires on the TreeViewItem (node) that I click on with the mouse, and then it continues to bubble up the control tree, even though I've set e.Handled = true on the RoutedEventArgs provided to the handler.  Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be ? I've double checked my code and I can see no reason why this should be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using TreeView.GotFocus when you really want TreeViewItem.Selected?

```
    <TreeView TreeViewItem.Selected="treeView1_Selected"  />
```

If you really want focus, use TreeViewItem.Focus instead so that items are targeted instead of the whole tree.

```
    <TreeView TreeViewItem.GotFocus="treeView1_GotFocus"/>
```

Comment: I was using focus when I should have been using selected, but I'm still curious : why was the focus event bubbling up even though I had marked the RoutedEventArgs as handled ?

Comment: RoutedEvents continue to bubble up even when you mark them as handled. Any subscriber can choose to receive handled events too. 
If you're working with WPF a lot, this is a good read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx

Comment: This answer, with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127614/preventing-wpf-treeviews-selecteditemchanged-event-from-bubbling  Solved my problem. Thank you all.